# svnadmin setrevprop with process substitution

Tags: svn

I tried to run the svnadmin command with the process substitution, but failed.

```
svnadmin setrevprop -r1 MyRepoDir svn:author <(echo -n NewAuthor)
```

The author name is replaced with an empty string. If I try with a "real" file, the author name is correctly set. Any hints what could be wrong?